# How to POST data from a Android Java button then load it in a web browser?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I open android browser with specified POST parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119827/how-can-i-open-android-browser-with-specified-post-parameters)

I have set up a Button that will link to Google Checkout, however, I need to POST a whole lot of required data (not GET) so I can't use the usual Intent method.

```
            //open the browser
            Uri u = Uri.parse(uri.toString());
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, u);
            startActivity(i);
```

How do I post data to a URL by pressing a button and then load the result into a web browser?  In this case it will be the Google Checkout webpage.

Comment: Hi there i would like to talk to you regarding adding parameters to a POST request in android

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following link for some details [Android Webview POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471581/android-webview-post). You will have to use a webview in your layout, you could submit the details then load the results into the webview.

Another which maybe of some use - although not to do with a webview: [Android JSON HttpClient to send data to PHP server with HttpResponse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540786/android-json-httpclient-to-send-data-to-php-server-with-httpresponse)

Comment: Is there a way to do this without needing webviews because the user will seed a https connection with the server for the entire session.  Will this be ok if I just load html into a webview?

Comment: I haven't really done any work with https, but from what I have read, as long as the signing authority behind the websites certificate is trusted by android, or added by you, it will work: [Android WebView with https loadUrl shows blank/empty page](http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2010/09/28/android-webview-with-https-loadurl-shows-blankempty-page/) another of interest: [Https Connection Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/995514/https-connection-android/1000205#1000205). I don't know if it is possible to post data via the browser intent though, I haven't seen it done that way.