# Android - open url with post data

Tags: android, post

In my application I need to open a WebMoney page (https) and send it POST data.
Or run the activity wm keeper (if fitted) and pass it the necessary data. Is it real?

Comment: [Have a look at this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4119827/593709)

Comment: I tried use WebView, but WebMoney site returns error. Maybe it's because of the HTTPS? Error is "Complete payment is impossible.
Exceeded the storage of information."