# Android: opening the browser with a POST request

Tags: android, android-intent, browser, http-post

By clicking on a button in my Android app, I would like to open the default browser and perform a POST request.

Any suggestion on how to achieve this?

Comment: @Rajesh, I would like to launch an external browser and not using a webview

Comment: Sorry, I did not **read** it right. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4119827/1321873.