# How to open an external browser using Intent.ACTION_VIEW and passing parameters to post?

Tags: android, post, android-intent, browser

I am having trouble opening the browser by sending data via post. Using the HTML form would be as follows:

```
<form method='post' action='https://cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/transactional/order/buynow' target='blank'>
<input type='hidden' name='id' value=xyz-xyz-xyz-xyz-xyz'
/>
<input type='image' name='submit' alt='Comprar' src='{Button Image}'>
</form>
```

However, when I make a call Intent in the Android browser opens a page with error.
I like this:

```
private String idCielo;

[...]

@Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/transactional/order/buynow"+idCielo));
                            getActivity().startActivity(browserIntent);

                    }
```

OR

```
@Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://cieloecommerce.cielo.com.br/transactional/order/buynow”));
                       browserIntent.putExtra("id",idCielo); 

                            getActivity().startActivity(browserIntent);

                    }
```

Please can help me. I must pass the value to post and open the page in a browser externally.
Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I open android browser with specified POST parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119827/how-can-i-open-android-browser-with-specified-post-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

just call the **ACTION.VIEW** intent and set a **datasource** to it

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 i.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.StackOverFlow.com"));
 startActivity(i);
```