# Post data with Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

Is there a way to send post data with url with Custom Chrome Tabs? Like it was with WebView:

```
webView.postUrl(String url, byte[] postData)
```

Cannot find any about it in [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/customtabs) or in [examples](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/custom-tabs-client)

Comment: Currently, CustomTabs only open URIs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I open android browser with specified POST parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119827/how-can-i-open-android-browser-with-specified-post-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not possible. You may be better off trying the approach described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30805339/97238 if you want to send a POST request.