# Android intent to POST URL?

Tags: android, http, post

I have the following code (simplified for simplicity) which takes the user to the URL specified:

```
    Button b = (Button) findViewById( R.id.button );
    b.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick( View v ) {
                Intent i = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW );
                i.setData( Uri.parse( "http://example.com/myform/?a=b&c=d&e=f" ) );
                if (i.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {                    
                            startActivity( i );
                }
        }
    } );
```

which works well, but is a little ugly because the CGI parameters are shown in the URL bar of the Android web browser (they're various ugly session keys, etc). Is there a way to do the same using HTTP POST so they're hidden?

Comment: I doubt it, since most apps that can receive such an intent won't be able to do a post.

Comment: "Yes We Can!"... but with a trick.

Check out this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4080517/launch-default-browser-with-intent-and-post-parameters#9909613

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible in the browser, but it would be possible if you used a `WebView`:

```
byte[] post = EncodingUtils.getBytes("a=b&c=d&e=f", "BASE64");
webview.postUrl("http://example.com/myform/", post);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I continued to use HTTP GET, but set a cookie then redirected the browser to a 'clean' URL without the session parameters.